# Create new paging tool bar in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slickgrid

I am a newbie in SlickGird.
I want to ask question about paging tool bar in SlickGrid.

The below picture is default when using SlickGird.

[image: Default of Slickgrid]

But, now i want to create paging tool bar like the following picture.
[image: user wanted]

So:

- Whether SlickGrid supports new tool bar (2nd picture) ?
- If yes, how to create this tool bar?

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: This is all happening inside the `slick.pager.js` function, if you search for the word `ui-icon-seek-first` you will see that this one represent the button first. These are jQuery UI icons and they use a class name to show the proper button, you could replace that with your text First instead with an ID on your button, then trigger the button with ID instead of triggering the class name. For the page number, it's a bit more tricky but it's still doable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new pager based on `controls\slick.pager.js` or just modify that file.